# Laravel Cors Middleware not working with POST Request

Tags: php, laravel, cors

So I am using `Laravel 5.8` as an `API` to a `ReactJS` view.

I already created a 'cors' middleware, i registered it on *Kernel.php* file, and I am using it on the api-routes that I am using. I tested using a GET Request and it worked, but when I test with a POST Request, I get the cors error:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/posts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So i have on my *api.php* ("/routes/api.php"):

```
Route::get('/posts', 'PostController@index')->middleware('cors');
Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store')->middleware('cors');
```

My *cors.php* middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  { 
    return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
  }
}
```

On my *Kernel.php* ("/app/Http/Kernel.php") I updated the "$routeMiddleware" array with my `'cors'` middleware

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Now in my React project, my *api.js* (where I made the code to make the requests):

```
// get Posts
export const getPosts = () => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/posts')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

// create new post
export const createPost = (post) => {

  return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/posts',
  {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(post)
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

I don't understand why everything is working fine when i try the `Get request`, but when i try the `Post Request`, i get the `CORS error`. Someone already had this problem?

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is not accepted by browser, you need to specify the domains allowed. no more jokers `*`

Answer (score 4):

So I was having the same problem and spent hours debugging and figuring out what was wrong when I was using my own CORS middlewares in api.php without using the fruitcake one (barryvdh/laravel-cors).

After hours of debugging and frustration I figured out that when you use a middleware in a group, then it doesn't get applied right away.

### **How laravel matches routes and "applies" middlewares:**

When you send a request, laravel reads the api.php and just "registers" all the routes and middlewares and "remembers" them without actually executing them. After it "registers" all of them (reads the whole `api.php` file), it executes a function where it inputs the path from the URL and the HTTP method that was used in the request and then it begins to find the route that matches the URL and HTTP method and after it finds one, it executes those middlewares that this route is located in and then it executes the controller methods.

So for example with your code when you send a `GET` request to `/api/posts`, it matches the resource method `index` and then executes the middleware `cors` and therefore it works and returns data from your controller.

### **Why POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH don't work with this approach:**

When you send a `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` or `PATCH` request to `/api/posts`, the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request first, so laravel "registers" all the routes and then it executes the "matching" using the URL and the HTTP method (it is `OPTIONS` right now).

But there is no route that has a method of `OPTIONS` and `resources` don't have an `OPTIONS` method either, so since there is no route that has an `OPTIONS` method, laravel doesn't match anything and therefore it does not execute those middlewares where you eventually handle `OPTIONS` methods.

> `api.php` example
>
> ```
> Route::post('/posts', 'PostController@store')->middleware('cors');
> ```

#### **The matching function in Laravel:**

The "matching" function is called `findRoute` and it is located in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`.

> ```
> /**
>  * Find the route matching a given request.
>  *
>  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
>  * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
>  */
> protected function findRoute($request)
> {
>     $this->current = $route = $this->routes->match($request);
>
>     $this->container->instance(Route::class, $route);
>
>     return $route;
> }
> ```

When you log `$route` with `error_log(json_encode($route), 0);`, then make a `GET` request and then look in error logs, you can see the succesful "match" and that it applied the `cors` controller:
`{"uri":"api\/posts","methods":["GET","HEAD"],"action":{"middleware":["cors"],"uses":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\PostController@index","controller":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\PostController@index","namespace":null,"prefix":"api","where":[]},"isFallback":false,"controller":null,"defaults":[],"wheres":[],"parameters":[],"parameterNames":[],"computedMiddleware":null,"compiled":{}}`

But when you send a `POST` request, this happens:
`{"uri":"api\/posts","methods":["OPTIONS"],"action":{"uses":{}},"isFallback":false,"controller":null,"defaults":[],"wheres":[],"parameters":[],"parameterNames":[],"computedMiddleware":null,"compiled":{}}`

There you can see that actually `OPTIONS` method was sent (because browser sends an `OPTIONS` method first) and nothing got matched and no middleware was applied and therefore the `PUT` request failed with a CORS error (`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`)

## **The summary and solution:**

- Middlewares in `$routeMiddleware` array get applied **after** Laravel succefully matches a route with the path and the HTTP method because different routes can have different middlwares.
- Middlewares in `$middleware` array (global middlewares) get applied **before** Laravel begins registering and matching routes.

To solve it, you **have to** use a global middleware in `$middleware` array, that handles the `OPTIONS` method. You can just use the [Fruitcake](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) one that handles it and then you can use your own CORS middlewares in `api.php` that can set different headers to your liking (for example different Allowed Origins for different routes/groups/prefixes.

Answer (score 3):

change your middleware to this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
  /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $domain = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    $host = '*';
    if (isset($domain['host'])) {
        $host = $domain['host'];
    }
    return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $host)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization,     X-Requested-With, Application');
  }
}
```

but once in production, you need to limit the allowed hosts by an environment variable.

You can also just use `barryvdh/laravel-cors` [Link here](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution and it did not worked. But i tried the 'barryvdh/laravel-cors' solution, and the thing is, it is working (as my first 'cors' middleware) when i try the GET Request, but when i try the POST Request i get the same error:

"Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/posts' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'..."

This is really weird.

Comment: I found something that helped me: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors/issues/360

I changed what i was returning from my Controller and strangely, it is working now the Post Request. (Using 'barryvdh/laravel-cors' solution)!

Comment: @JulioW. happy to lead you to the right solution for you. you had some `echo` in your code ?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that solved this issue for me was to put the cors middleware class  in the top of `$middleware` array in `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,

    ];
```

here is the cors middleware i am using

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
        $response->header("Access-Control-Max-Age","600");    // cache for 10 minutes

        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"); //Make sure you remove those you do not want to support

        $response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application");

        return $response;
    }

}
```

hope it will help someone someday.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using FormData instead of JSON.stringfy:

So, I changed:

```
let data = JSON.stringify({firstname:'John', familyname: 'Doe'});
```

to:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('firstname','John');
data.append('lastname','Doe');
```

and the complete code is something like this:

```
fetch(YOUR_API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
    }).then(
    res =>res.json()
        .then(res => console.log(res))
    ).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the route type to any

```
Route::any(/*your path goes here*/)->middleware('cors');
```