# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios, cors

So I know the issue here is that im trying to send a POST request from `example.com` to `localhost`.   What I'm not sure about is why this isn't working, as from what I can tell, I've added everything to Laravel via the nuclear option.

In Laravel, I've added to my `public/index.php` the following:

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'):
```

I know this isn't the ideal way to do this, however I was having the same issues using Cors middleware too.

My client is a React app using Axios to send a POST request from the browser, and in the network tab I can see the following:

[image]

My Axios request looks like so:

```js
await axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/webhooks/platform',
  data: notification.data,
  headers: {
    Origin: 'https://example.com'
  }
});
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?  My versions are below, and are strict. I cannot change these:

```json
{
  "php": "^7.1.3",
  "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
  "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.5",
  "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
  "nexmo/laravel": "^2.4",
}
```

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39462686/979099) but I'm getting `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

**app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range');
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
       ......
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::post('/webhooks/platform', 'WebhooksController@handlePlatformNotification') -> middleware('cors');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend your solution, I hope it help you:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,X-Token-Auth,Authorization')
```

To implement all this "header" logic I recommend you to use [Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware)

If you deal with it and want to see extended and flexible solving of CORS problem - check [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-cors#laravel) package

**UPD**: It seems the problem is in 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' wildcard.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19744754/7155723) answer for details

**UPD2**: Btw, check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#sorting-middleware). If your own middleware not even fire - problem in middleware priority

Comment: So I jus tried this with middleware, adding the origin, methods, credentials and headers as middleware but still get the same issue.  Will update question with code

Comment: hmmm, when I faced with CORS problem I have had one more problem with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' wildcard (*). Coud you test your solution without it?

Comment: I'm not convinced the Cors implementation is even working.  Looking at the OPTIONS call to the server, the response doesn't have any of the Access Control headers added to it

Comment: Maybe problem in middleware priority

Comment: Yup thought that too but adding in Cors at the top hasn't helped :(

Comment: Do U use Laravel Passport?

Comment: Nope, nothing like that.  Only the packages that are in the question.  I've done some logging in the middleware. If i call directly from postman its logging, but from the browser, nothing :/

Comment: Fixed it.  Nothing to do with anything like this :(. All to do with how Laravel routes requests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042612/laravel-cors-middleware-not-working-with-post-request