# Laravel 5.8: How to get the matched URL path without queries or parameters in the middle ware?

Tags: url, laravel-5, routes

I'm trying to get current url in laravel without any parameters or query parameters,
let's assume I've this route in the api.php file:

```
test/{id}/get-test-data/{type}
```

and the url is

```
test/395/get-test-data/temp
```

I need to log this basic url in the middle-ware `test/{id}/get-test-data/{type}` and not the one with parameters,

I've tried this

```
$route = \Route::current();
$route->uri;
```

it worked, but when the endpoint being hit the middle-ware print the $route->uri twice as the following

```
test/395/get-test-data/temp
test/{id}/get-test-data/{type}
```

is there any way to avoid printing the first line?

Comment: If you want to match the route, assign a route name to the route then you’ll be able to check the route name in the middleware

Comment: There are too many routes and we can't name them all, and we need something scalable so if any developer put new route without name, the middleware keeps working normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042612/laravel-cors-middleware-not-working-with-post-request)

> When you send a POST, PUT, DELETE or PATCH request to /api/posts, the browser sends an OPTIONS request first, so laravel "registers" all the routes and then it executes the "matching" using the URL and the HTTP method (it is OPTIONS right now).
>
> But there is no route that has a method of OPTIONS and resources don't
> have an OPTIONS method either, so since there is no route that has an
> OPTIONS method, laravel doesn't match anything and therefore it does
> not execute those middlewares where you eventually handle OPTIONS
> methods.

So the solution is to filter out these option requests in the middleware:

```
if ($request->method() != 'OPTIONS') {
        ...
}
```